# Controls re-initialization using WatiN

Tags: watin

I ran in to a situation where I need to re-initialize the controls of each page when the page gets loaded for each test. I have separated the controls declaration of a page in one code file and operation that are performed on those controls in another code file.

I have exposed those operations to the test cases, so that no controls are passed from test cases.
I have implemented Singleton for controls initialization. Due to this, the first test case excutes with out any issues. When second test kicks off, it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when trying to access control that is already initialized.

```
public partial class Login : Page
{
    protected TextField txtUserName;
    protected TextField txtPassword;
    protected TextField txtConPassword;

    public Login()
      {
        this.txtUserName = Util.Browser.TextField(Find.ById("username"));
        this.txtPassword = Util.Browser.TextField(Find.ById("password"));
        this.txtConPassword = Util.Browser.TextField(Find.ByValue("password"));
      }
 }



public partial class Login

  {
    /// <summary>

    /// Set user name.

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="userName">User name.</param>

    public void SetUserName(string userName)
    {
        this.txtUserName.TypeText(userName);
        //Util.SetTextHelper(this.txtUserName, userName);
    }
 }
```

I guess the controls get initialized only when Browser gets loaded with Document. When the first test ends, Browser gets closed and disposed. So when the Browser gets re-initialized (for the second test) with the document since the controls initialization implemented using a Singleton, the control values throws the error.

This issue can be resolved by not implementing Singleton, but re-initializing the controls where ever required does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED!  Try using the WatiN FindBy attribute...

```
public partial class LoginPage : Page
{
    [FindBy(Id = "username")]
    public TextField txtUserName;

    [FindBy(Id = "password")]
    public TextField txtPassword;

    [FindBy(Value = "password")]
    public TextField txtConPassword;
}

public partial class LoginPage
{
    public void SetUserName(string userName)
    {
        this.txtUserName.TypeText(userName);
    }
}

public void LoginTest()
{
    using (IE browser = new IE())
    {
        browser.GoTo("http://yourLoginPage.html");

        LoginPage loginPage = browser.Page<LoginPage>();
        loginPage.SetUserName("some_username");

        //Do your other stuff

        //If you haven't navigated away from the page this should still work
        //If not just grab the login page again: -
        //loginPage = browser.Page<LoginPage>();
        loginPage.SetUserName("some_other_username");
    }
}
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks Phil, but using the above syntax I guess i need to initialize the page in the test cases!!! And more over we can not have multiple attributes declared with the above syntax. Correct me If I am wrong. Thanks, Sham_

Comment: Hi Sham, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "initialize the page in the test cases", but this is how we've been using the pages (I've updated the example with a bit more detail)

Comment: Thanks again Phil for such a detiailed explanation. However I am planning to separate the Framework part from TestCases. I mean I can not guarantee that I will always be using WatiN as my tool. Assume If I want to migrate to Selenuim.. I dont want sit and update the all the test cases.. Because even if tool changes test cases need not to be modifed. If possible, Just Ping me your alias (email -id) so that I can mail you a sample project of my requirement... Again Thanks a lot Phil.

Comment: Sham, I think I see what you mean now.  We have a base class that creates the browser instance on TestSetup, but every time we need to use a page we call - MyPage page = browser.Page<MyPage>();  I'm not 100% sure, but I think you'll always have to do that.

Comment: Yes, you are true, we need to initialize the page before we use those controls. Thanks Phil